# Invalid bundle. Apps that support Multitasking on iPad must provide the app’s launch screen using an Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode14

i had some issue while i am trying to upload the app on app store. Invalid bundle. Apps that support Multitasking on iPad must provide the app’s launch screen using an Xcode storyboard, or using UILaunchScreen if the app’s MinimumOSVersion is 14 or higher. Verify that the UILaunchStoryboardName key is included in your com.SSPLOrbit.Orbit bundle if you’re using a storyboard.
[This is the error i am facing while uploading the app on app store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81DwO.png)